# Generate UUID via Envoy Proxy

Tags: envoyproxy

I am trying to use the following envoy extension to associate an uuid in the x-request-id HTTP header

```
type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.request_id.uuid.v3.UuidRequestIdConfig
```

This is my working yaml , there is just one api that I have exposed via envoy

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10001
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: edge
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
          route_config:
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: direct_response_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/v1/hello"
                route:
                  cluster: cluster1        
  clusters:
  - name: cluster1
    connect_timeout: 5s
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster1
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 8080
```

My question is in the above yaml where do I add the extension of uuid generation

```
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.request_id.uuid.v3.UuidRequestIdConfig
          pack_trace_reason: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put this extension in the `HttpConnectionManager` config (under `request_id_extension`) :

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          request_id_extension:
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.request_id.uuid.v3.UuidRequestIdConfig
              pack_trace_reason: false
...
```

I have found the information in the documentation here : https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#extensions-filters-network-http-connection-manager-v3-httpconnectionmanager (search `request_id_extension` in the page).

This attribute is defined in the proto file here : https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/v1.21.0/api/envoy/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#L626-L642.